# API Gateway Integration Request Mapping

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am using Api Gateway to add a new entry to DynamoDB.
i am using $context.requestTimeEpoch as a timeStamp.
what i need is to use timeStamp and ID sent by a client as below but it is only adding _ID in the DynamoDb, not timeStamp_ID.

```
 "reviewId": {
    "S": "$context.requestTimeEpoch_$input.path('$.ID')"
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: The notation seems ambiguous, it looks like the `_` causes the expression to refer to `$context.requestTimeEpoch_` ... perhaps you want `"S": "${context.requestTimeEpoch}_$input.path('$.ID')"`?

Comment: Yes, Perfect, Thanks @Michael-sqlbot